# Regex matching character within

Tags: regex

Looking to match `WS-810-REFERENCE-1` where the string must have -'s within it

And can't think of something to work perfectly
`[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+`

That will match but will also match words that do not have the - character

Thought of maybe this `([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\-)+`
But that will match WS-810-REFERENCE- missing the final segment.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used a modified version of the second attempt just to grab that extra missing section
`((?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\-)+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for lookahead to make sure hyphen is present in the string. You can use:

```
\b(?=\w*?-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?= |$)
```

#### Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/pZ6hV6

Comment: Matching only words not entire lines, so I tried (?=.*?-)[a-zA-Z0-9-]+ but that also matches strings without hyphens

Comment: pardon...do you know the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343637/normalize-paths-with-parent-directories-in-the-middle-in-bash-script)

Comment: @MortezaLSC: sorry I don't know python.